# What would be the message field in Pubnub.Subscribe when the data has been published via another platform

Tags: javascript, python, pubnub

I am getting my data from a python API and thus publishing the data to my pubnub channel via Python. But for charting I have to rely on  javascript and hence for subscribing to the same channel via javascript. My question is that when how would I get messages field while I am listening to the channel. My best guess is that we would need to create a separate variable but how to populate that with my published messages?

Here is my code:

```
data = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='checkpoint.pause')
pubnub = Pubnub(publish_key='xxx',subscribe_key='xxx')

def timesTamp(data):
    for each in data:
        x = each.timestamp

def counterVolume(data):
    for each in data:
        y = each.counter_volume
        pubnub.publish( channel='my_channel', message=y )
```

### Listening Via javascript:

```
var pubnub = PUBNUB({
                  publish_key   : 'xxx',
                  subscribe_key : 'xxx'
                          } );

pubnub.subscribe({
              channel: 'my_channel',
              message: y
              });

var channel = "c3-spline" + Math.random();
eon.chart({
            history: true,
            channel: channel,
               flow: true,
            generate: {
                  bindto: '#chart',
                          data: {
                               y: 'y',
                            labels: false
                              },
                axis : {
                       x : {
                     type : 'timeseries',
                      tick: {
                     format: '%H:%M:%S'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Imo we are working on a response for you and will have details shortly.

Comment: First glance, make sure to remove `setInterval({..})` wrapper as soon as you can.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should do is remove `setInterval(function(){});` from you code. This is unnecessary.

Second, if you look at the [parameter list](https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart#quickstart) within the EON docs you'll notice a `message` parameter.

This is the same exact callback as found in `punub.subscribe` and will respond whenever you receive a message on that channel.

Comment: Thank you Ian or your answer. I guess that I should rephrase my question a little bit, what I do not understand is that once the message is published in what form it is received by the subscriber, is it message {data inside} or just simple data? how would a subscribe know where the data is. if for example there are 2 variables x and y.